# Send a Codename One iOS AppStore build to App Store

Tags: codenameone

I have a Codename One iOS AppStore build. I filled all required data in https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/, but it's written that "**you can upload a build using Xcode or Application Loader**". I supposed that I don't need a Mac to publish an app: am I wrong?

Comment: The store upload is the one point which we didn't cover yet. FYI it's something we can theoretically implement similarly to the certificate wizard if this is important to you (it's a bit complex so we didn't do that piece). At the moment you will need a Mac and Application Loader, you can use a solution such as [mac in cloud](http://www.macincloud.com/) to do that part

Comment: Thank you Shai, don't worry: today I tried MacInCloud, it's enough to upload an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need macOS to instal Xcode and Application Loader, and yes you would need a Mac if you want to develop for iOS. It doesn't need to be the most expensive model though, even a second hand Mac mini would do.

Comment: Hi tomi44g, I accepted your answer, however it's partially not correct: I develop for iOS, Android, Javascript and theoretically for all the other platforms and devices supported by Codename One and I don't need a Mac neither XCode, I use Linux and Netbeans, because the code is Java. The Mac, at the moment, is necessary only to upload the app after developing it. Moreover, an iDevice (like an iPhone, an iPad or even a Mac) is necessary to create new certificates because the required two factors authentication.